# Anaconda says environment I currently have active does not exist

Tags: python, environment, anaconda, conda

So I am very new to Python, and I downloaded Anaconda to get started. I am going through the Conda "test drive" walk-through to get myself familiar, and I am having a issue with my machine not responding as the walk-through says it should.

```
C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
env1                     C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\envs\env1
env2                     C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\envs\env2
py2                      C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\envs\py2
root                  *  C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3


C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)

C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>activate py2
Activating environment ""C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\Scripts\..\envs"\py2"...

[py2] C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)

[py2] C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>conda list
Error: Error: environment does not exist: C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\"C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\envs"\py2
#
# Use 'conda create' to create an environment before listing its packages.
[py2] C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>

[py2] C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>deactivate
Deactivating environment ""C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3\Scripts\..\envs"\py2"...

C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  C:\Users\barry\Anaconda3
```

Why does it thin the environment does not exist when it does? It has been activated even, its the current environment, so how can it not exist?

The other strange thing is that if I deactivate, and then ask to see the list of environments, all the ones I created are gone.

If I close the command prompt and reopen it, I can again see the environments I created, but the same behavior persists.

I am using Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: There is currently a lot of activity around the Windows bugs in `activate.bat`. I am not sure what the current status is, but you can try to use the latest version of `activate.bat` from https://github.com/conda/conda-env/blob/develop/bin/activate.bat.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the bat file with the version you sent and it now works perfectly. I am so amazed. This is my first stack Overflow post and it was a success. A million thanks